# Conflicting types and previous declaration of x was here...what?

Tags: c, function, void

I've been teaching myself C for a few months when I have time, and I have run into a problem I am not sure how to fix.

Specifically, when I try to compile this using gcc, I get:

```
geometry.c:8: error: conflicting types for ‘trapezoid’
geometry.c:7: note: previous declaration of ‘trapezoid’ was here
geometry.c:48: error: conflicting types for ‘trapezoid’
geometry.c:7: note: previous declaration of ‘trapezoid’ was here
geometry.c:119: error: conflicting types for ‘trapezoid_area’
geometry.c:59: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘trapezoid_area’ was here
geometry.c: In function ‘cone_volume’:
geometry.c:128: error: called object ‘3.14100000000000001421085471520200371742248535156e+0’ is not a function
geometry.c: In function ‘cylinder_volume’:
geometry.c:136: error: called object ‘3.14100000000000001421085471520200371742248535156e+0’ is not a function
```

Now, I think I may need to typecast the functions, but again, I am not sure.

It looks like it wants to read PI, which I had defined as 3.141, as a function. Is there a way I can avoid using the magic number 3.141 (though it's much less of a magic number than others)?

```
//Geometric formulae
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.141

float trapezoid(float b1, float b2, float h);
int trapezoid();
float sphere_volume(float r);
int sphere();
float cone_volume(float r, float h);
int cone();
float pyramid_volume(float b, float h);
int pyramid();
float cylinder_volume(float r, float h);
int cylinder();

int main(void) {
        char selection = 0;

        while(selection != 'q') {
                printf("\t--Geometric Formulas--\n");
                printf("\tSelection an option from the menu: ");
                scanf("%c", & selection);
                switch(selection) {
                        case 1: //Trapezoid area
                                printf("%d", trapezoid());
                                break;
                        case 2: //Sphere volume
                                printf("%d", sphere());
                                break;
                        case 3: //Cone volume
                                printf("%d", cone());
                                break;
                        case 4: //Pyramid volume
                                printf("%d", pyramid());
                                break;
                        case 5: //Cylinder volume
                                printf("%d", cylinder());
                                break;
                        default:
                                break;
                }
        }
}
//      --Shape Menus--
//Trapezoid
int trapezoid() {
        float h = 0, b1 = 0, b2 = 0;
        float traparea;

        printf("\tTrapezoid base 1: ");
        scanf("%3f", &b1);
        printf("\tTrapezoid base 2: ");
        scanf("%3f", &b2);
        printf("\tTrapezoid height: ");
        scanf("%3f", &b2);

        traparea = trapezoid_area(b1, b2, h);

        printf("\tTrapezoid Area: %3f\n", traparea); }

//Sphere
int sphere() {
        float r = 0;
        float spherevol;

        printf("\tSphere radius: ");
        scanf("%f", &r);

        spherevol = sphere_volume(r);

        printf("\tSphere volume: %3f\n", spherevol); }

//Cone
int cone() {
        float r = 0, h = 0;
        float conevol;

        printf("\tCone radius: ");
        scanf("%f", &r);
        printf("\tCone height: ");
        scanf("%f", &h);

        conevol = cone_volume(r, h);

        printf("\tCone volume: %3f\n", conevol); }

//Pyramid
int pyramid() {
        float b = 0, h = 0;
        float pyramidvol;

        printf("\tPyramid base: ");
        scanf("%f", &b);
        printf("\tPyramid height: ");
        scanf("%f", &h);

        pyramidvol = pyramid_volume(b, h);

        printf("\tPyramid volume: %3f\n", pyramidvol); }

//Cylinder
int cylinder() {
        float r = 0, h = 0;
        float cylindervol;

        printf("\tCylinder radius: ");
        scanf("%f", &r);
        printf("\tCylinder height: ");
        scanf("%f", &h);

        cylindervol = cylinder_volume(r, h);

        printf("Cylinder volume: %3f", cylindervol); }

//      --Geometric Formulas--
//Trapezoid Area Computation
float trapezoid_area(float b1, float b2, float h) {
        return ((b1 + b2) * h) / 2; }

//Sphere Volume Computation
float sphere_volume(float r) {
        return ((pow(r,3)) * (4 * PI)) / 3; }

//Cone Volume Computatioin
float cone_volume(float r, float h) {
        return ((PI(pow(r,2)) * h)) / 3; }

//Pyramid Volume Computation
float pyramid_volume(float b, float h) {
        return (b * h) / 3; }

//Cylinder Volume Computation
float cylinder_volume(float r, float h) {
        return (PI(pow(r,2))) * h; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any of them that say there was an 'implicit' definition: this can be solved by pre-declaring it.  As an example, you pre-declared *float trapezoid* and *int trapezoid*, but you didn't pre-declare *trapezoid_area*.  As others pointed out, you also can't overload in C as you can in C++.

In a few areas you're trying to do implicit multiplication -- eg, *PI(pow(r,2))* should be *PI * (pow(r,2))*.

Comment: Not that I mind the nomination, but ... I only answered a very small portion of the question.  Are you sure you meant to select mine as the correct answer?

Answer (score 5):

The errors you're seeing are because you're defining the same function twice with different signatures

```
float trapezoid(float b1, float b2, float h);
int trapezoid();
```

Based on your other definitions it looks like the first `trapezoid` functions should be named `trapezoid_volume`

```
float trapezoid_volume(float b1, float b2, float h);
int trapezoid();
```

Comment: The different signature generates this type of error (confirmed).

Answer (score 3):

**C** does not support function overloading. **C++** does.

And since you accidentally declared `trapezoid_volume` as `trapezoid`, you get a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

you defined twice function trapezoid.
C isn't C++. You can't define the same function with different signatures like you do in C++ using overloading features.

Comment: Thank you...fixed...but now it displays
/tmp/ccn6YvQ0.o: In function `sphere_volume':
geometry.c:(.text+0x39d): undefined reference to `pow'
/tmp/ccn6YvQ0.o: In function `cone_volume':
geometry.c:(.text+0x3d0): undefined reference to `pow'
/tmp/ccn6YvQ0.o: In function `cylinder_volume':
geometry.c:(.text+0x41b): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Bowlslaw: you haven't linked math library. Try gcc with -lm option if you are using linux.

Comment: The -lm option worked, even though I have linked the math.h library.

Comment: I know this is a 12 year old post, but you aren't "linking" math.h, it's not an object or library file. It's a header file, and you're INCLUDING it in your .c file to provide various definitions to the compiler.

Linking is the process of combining your compiled object file(s) into either an executable or library file.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define PI 3.141

float trapezoid(float b1, float b2, float h);
int trapezoid();
```

I think you want

```
float trapezoid_volume(...);
/*             ^^^^^^^                 */
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about defining `PI` - pi is usually defined in `math.h` (as `M_PI`), but since it's not part fo the actual standard you might need to do some configuration to get it.

For example, when using MSVC you need to define `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` to get it. See

- http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Mathematical-Constants.html
- http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Trig-Functions.html#Trig-Functions

  for the GNU C library's information.

If your platform doesn't have it, you might want to throw something like the following into a header:

```
#ifndef
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327
#endif
```